# how to get the client port of a URLConnection in java

Tags: java, networking

Is it possible to get the client side port number of a URLConnection in java, I didn't find any method to do that.

edit:
I am on client side. As java API said, it will try to use the same connection for any URL, just like set "keep-alive" to true. And I want to verify this by:

1: create a URL by using new URL(someurl)

2: create a second URL by using new URL(someurl), the same ulr

3: get the client port for both 1 and 2. If they are the same, then there should be the same connection, meaning java reuse the connect as setting keep-alive.

Comment: There isn't one. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: Are you on the client side or on server side? Both ports are available on both client and server, but I don't know what API can be used to get the opposite port.

Comment: @Arkadiy Your comment makes zero sense. URLConnection is used at the client; he isn't asking about the opposite port; and if you really think the local port is available via URLConnection please tell us how.

Comment: @EJP - ultimately an HTTP connection maps into an open socket. The port the socket is bound to probably can be accessed via some api (getsockname?). But Java hides this link, so you are right: no way to do it in Java. In fact, good OO programming requires this to be hidden at this level. If you need access to this kind of details, you need to use much lower levels of Java library.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to get the client side port number of a URLConnection
>   in java

No, it is not possible and there is no method through which you can get that.

Answer (score 1):

there is no such method in java.